# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

Tags: java, jersey, xhtml

index.html

```
  <html>
  <body>
   <h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
   <p><a href="webresources/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
    <p>Visit the <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
    for more information on Jersey!
   </body>
   </html>
```

MyResource.java

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

/** Method processing HTTP GET requests, producing "text/plain" MIME media
 * type.
 * @return String that will be send back as a response of type "text/plain".
 */
@GET 
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getIt() {
    return "Hi there!";
}
}
```

Error is Comming

```
  HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw        exception

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from      fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web   Application threw exception
     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


root cause 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA()Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;
       com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.<init>(AnnotationScannerListener.java:94)
      com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.<init>(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
     com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
     com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
      org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache      Tomcat/7.0.67 logs.
```

Comment: which jersey version do you use?

Comment: Please provide `web.xml` and `pom` or dependency list. @Meiko it's 1.\*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652337/jersey-rest-nosuchmethoderror-com-sun-jersey-core-reflection-reflectionhelper

Comment: @Meiko why the version important for this ??

Comment: It looks like an incompatibility of libraries. I assume you have different versions of libraries of jersey in the runtime than when compiling the project. Or something similar...

Comment: @IndianProgrammer1234, Can you paste web.xml file here will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

you would have use correct version if you want proper output latest version number is 1.19.1 use this try onee

Comment: Changing the version does'nt help, if you haven't declared the correct artifacts resp. imported the correct libs.

Answer (score 0):

May be problem with servelet api dependcy : 
use this in your maven pom for exemple:

```
   <!-- servlet api 3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems a java version issue. compile the code with supporting jar(java version) only